# How should I build-up this structure?

Tags: c, struct

So the first part of the task is to create a structure in the following way:

1. the trains id (integer)
2. time ( two integers separated by a colon)
3. whether they will arrive or start (0 for arrival and 1 for start)

I have no problem with the 1 and 3. But I have no clue how should I do the 2 because of the column.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean two integers separate by a colon, not column? That is just how it is displayed. Inside the structure, just put two integers.

Comment: Yes, I meant a colon, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways.  Here is one:

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    int hr;//hr/min can be arranged in a string separated by a space (or colon)
    int min;
    bool direction;//where arriving == false, departing == true
}train_s;

train_s train;
```

This can be used to create a single instance or an array...

```
   int main(void)
   {
       char time[6];//create buffer to contain two column time string
       train_s train = {0};//single instance

       train.id = 12345;
       train.hr = 10;
       train.min = 35;
       train.direction = true;
       //arrange hr & min into 2 column string using time buffer
       sprintf(time, "%d:%d", train.hr, train.min);
       ...
```

Or a string can be used for time that would allow room for values of hr. and min. arranged into colon separated columns....

```
typedef struct {
    int id;
    char time[6];//eg "12:00"
    bool direction;//where arriving == false, departing == true
}train_s;     

....

int main(void) 
{     //array of instances...
      train_s train[5] = {{12345, "12:00", 0},
                          {23452, "13:45", 1},
                          {67893, "15:38", 1},
                          {67801, "01:30", 0},
                          {73356, "02:45", 1}};
```

Comment: Minor fix [to code comment]: OP wants direction: 0=arrival, 1=departure

Comment: @CraigEstey - done, I hope boolean will be okay.